# JVM - Open Webpage and run Javascript code

Tags: javascript, java, jvm, kotlin

I figured out that you can open a webpage like this (I am using Kotlin btw.)

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI(url))
}
```

Is it now possible to run some javascript code on the current webpage I just opened to click buttons etc.? (Without using external libraries like Selenium).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it yourself to find out whether or not it is possible?

Comment: Well, if it is possible I suppose that there ia sone function I can pass a string which executes it, which I haven't found yet.